# Why am I receiving the following error message when uploading CSV Improved? Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package

Tags: xml, joomla1.5

I have access to a clients Joomla site and I need to export their products from Virtuemart to be able to import them into the new site I'm building for them.

I've never used Joomla & I'm trying to install the extension CSV Improved to be able to export their products from virtuemart, however, when I try and upload the file I get the following message 'Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package.'

The site is using Version 1.5 22

Has anyone else received this message, or know how to solve this?

This is the download for the extension: https://csvimproved.com/downloads/csvi-free/csvi-free-5-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install an extension designed for a later version of Joomla. Official support for Joomla 1.5 ended in 2012 and the Joomla 1.5 versions of extensions are often no longer available on developer websites.

If you can't find a suitable extension, you could migrate Joomla 1.5 to the latest version of Joomla and more extension choice would then be available.

Another option might be to export the data directly from the database table(s) using phpMyAdmin or similar.